# Add HTML to Page with Javascript + Variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance, nested

So, I'm going to be adding and removing a lot of content to an HTML page with relatively complicated styling and data-sets that will depend on the clicked element. An example would look something like this...

```
<li class="foo">
    <div class="slider" data-one="foo" data-two="bar"></div>
    <img class="thumb" src="img/foo.png" alt="foo" />
    <input class="sliderInput" type="number" data-one="foo" min="0" max="240">
</li>
```

Now, `foo` and `bar` will be determined based on the initially clicked element (almost 100 of them, and very rarely will we see more than 4-5 at a time, so I'm avoiding writing it all out in plain HTML.

After some research, I was going to do something along these lines... but it felt very dirty to do so:

```
function createSlider(foo){
  var fooLi = $('<li></li>').addClass(troop);
  fooLi.append($('<div></div>').addClass('slider').data('one', foo).data('two', database[troop]["two"]));
  fooLi.append($('<img />').attr({
    src: 'img/' + foo + '.png',
    alt: foo
  });
  fooLi.append($('<input />').addClass('sliderInput').data('one', foo).attr({
    type: 'number',
    min: 0,
    max: 240
  }));
  $('#whatever').append(fooLi);
}
```

Is this a reasonable way to do this with jQuery? Or is there something more efficient I'm not seeing here?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this link: https://jsperf.com/jquery-append-vs-html-list-performance/103

They evaluate the speed (in ops/sec) with different ways of creating / adding / appending elements to the DOM